# Chrome freezes when I upload any files with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

I recently updated my laptop to 22.04 and when I try to upload any files the browser completely freezes. Is there a workaround for this?  I usually have multiple tabs open for work and this completely disturbs the work cycle.

Comment: Upload what to where?

Comment: When I upload files in gmail or in gchat, the whole browser freezes and I'm not able to switch ower  any tabs

Comment: Additional/requested information should be [edit]ed in the question, not just comments. While at that... Are we to assume other browsers (e.g. Firefox) work as expected for the same task?

Comment: Yes it works fine